# PHP auto post on facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to auto post on Facebook page using my app it works fine if I replace **my-page-numeric-id** with my profile numeric id,  but when I put my page numeric id instead of **my-page-numeric-id** and put valid **access toke**n it won't publish on Facebook page I tried to submit review permission that are as follow "manage_pages, publish_actions" but Facebook team mentioned that you don't need it all because you own this page and your currently admin of it, these permission are necessary when any other person need to authorize with your app. 
Now my question is, my code works perfectly for publishing post on my profile's wall but i am unable to auto post on my page what is the problem behind it i am unable to figure out here is my code

```
<?php
 require_once 'src/facebook.php';
class FacebookApi {

    var $consumer;
    var $token;
    var $method;
    var $http_status;
    var $last_api_call;
    var $callback;
    var $connection;
    var $access_token;

    function __construct($data){
        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = $data['consumer_key'];
        $config['secret'] = $data['consumer_secret'];

        $this->connection = new Facebook($config);

    }

    function share($title, $targetUrl, $imgUrl, $description, $access_token){

        $this->connection->setAccessToken($access_token);

        $params["access_token"] = $access_token;
        if(!empty($title)){
            $params["message"] = $title;
            $params["name"] = $title;
        }
        if(!empty($targetUrl)){
            $params["link"] = $targetUrl;
        }
        if(!empty($imgUrl)){
            $params["picture"] = $imgUrl;
        }
        if(!empty($description)){
            $params["description"] = $description;
        }

        // post to Facebook
        try {
          $ret = $this->connection->api('/my-page-numeric-id/feed', 'POST', $params);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
          $e->getMessage();
        }

        return true;
    }

    function getLoginUrl($params){
        return $this->connection->getLoginUrl($params);
    }

    function getContent($url) {
        $ci = curl_init();
        /* Curl settings */
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt( $ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 );

        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $response = curl_exec($ci);
        curl_close ($ci);
        return $response;
      }
}

$access_token = 'long-live-token-here';
$facebookData = array();
$facebookData['consumer_key'] = 'app-id-here';
$facebookData['consumer_secret'] = 'app-secret-here';

$title = "Demo Content Posted on Timeline";
$targetUrl = "http://www.demo_url.com/1234-post";
$imgUrl = "http://www.demo_url.com/1234-post-image.png";
$description = "demo_description_here"; 

$facebook = new FacebookApi($facebookData);
$facebook->share($title, $targetUrl, $imgUrl, $description, $access_token);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now it's time for facebook v5 sdk

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app_id',
  'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
  ]);
             // facebook auto post

$params = array(
  "message" => "$title in $merchant   $short",
  "link" => "http://pickmyoffers.com/",
  "picture" => "http://Pickmyoffers.com/images/searched/Flipkart.png",
  "name" => "www.Pickmyoffers.com",
  "caption" => "www.pickmyoffers.com",
  "description" => "Submit Coupon and earn money through Pickmyoffers.com | Deals,Coupons and offers."
);
            $post = $fb->post('/Page_id/feed',$params, $access_token);
            $post = $post->getGraphNode()->asArray();

}
```

hope it's help

Answer (score 4):

With API v2.3, they have split the publishing permission into two separate ones:

- `publish_actions` is for anything you want to publish *as a user*
- if you want to publish as a page however, you need `publish_pages` permission (in addition to `manage_pages`)

Comment: how i should put permissions in my code and where should i add

Comment: There where you asked for the other permission before already? If you don’t know how the login flow works, please go check the documentation and SDK examples. (Looks like you’re using the old PHP SDK v3, I think official documentation for that is not available any more.)