# Facebook: auto post on wall of a Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token

Here is a problem that drives me crazy for weeks!

For more than a year, I published automatically my website's articles on my 2 facebook Pages, directly on the wall (the main stream?). It worked like a charm.
However, since March, these publications have moved to Publication->Visitors Publication (sorry for the translation but my FB is in French) so they are almost invisible!

Do you know if there was a change in FB policy regarding publishing on pages?I know that I use an old PHP SDK (3.1.1) but I can't update because of my server that doesn't have PHP 5.6! However I thing if it's a SDK version issue so the publish would be simply impossible...

Technically, a cron task on my webserver send the request with my FB App id and secret code, and use my personnal access token to publish. As I'm the admin of the pages with "manage_pages,publish_actions" rights, there was no problem.
I read some topics that talk about "publish_pages" but to use this, you need to submit your App to FB for validation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32143270/985357

The FB support has a page that explains the differences between user and page access token. But it's unclear :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

I also try to get the access token of one of my Page in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer but when I try to use it, I had the "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

Here is my code:

```html
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/include/facebook/facebook.php'; //facebook SDK
    
$this->oFB = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => self::FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
 'secret' => self::FACEBOOK_SECRET,  'cookie' => true));

//then

$this->oFB->api('/{MyPageId}/feed', 'post',$this->FB_params);

//with FB_params populate:
$FB_params= array('access_token' => self::FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PERSO,
                'from' => self::FACEBOOK_APP_ID) ;

//... and ....
$FB_params['to'] = $FB::FACEBOOK_MY_PAGEID ;
$FB_params['message'] = "blabla....." ;
$FB_params['link'] = "url..." ;

/*the way I use to get my FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PERSO:
1- hit :
"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".FACEBOOK_APP_ID."&redirect_uri=http://www.website.com/token.php&scope=manage_pages,publish_actions"
2- hit : https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".FACEBOOK_APP_ID."&redirect_uri=http://www.website.com/token.php&client_secret=".FACEBOOK_SECRET."&code=".$_GET['code']
3- access token-> $_GET['access_token']
*/
```

Final question: Initially I had a unlimited access token now, with the same method, it is time limited to 2 months. Is it also a change in FB policy?

Sorry for this loOOOOong post but I hope you will understand that I search the web for a longtime without any solution.
Thank you!

Comment: you are probably now using a user token instead of a page token. debug the token.

Comment: Yes, you need publish_pages permission, and no, you do not need to submit your app for review. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: luschn : yes I always used a user token and it worked. But I finally understand thanks to CBroe !

In fact when you have the FB Screen that explains that you must ask for a review, Click OK anyway in the lower right corner. It will work !

But you need to get the page access token (ATP) for each page you want to publish on. Store them in order to PHP can use them when your script want to publish your latest news.

The only thing i'm not sure yet is there is a expiration date four the ATP ? As your user token expires, I assume that the ATP expire too.

THANKS A LOT !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need Appid, App secret and access token. Please Be Secret all of Ids

```
$graphUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APPID .'&client_secret='.APPSECRET.'&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token='.ACCESS_TOKEN;

$accessToken = @file_get_contents($graphUrl);
parse_str($accessToken); //get the access_token param in the string and would be named $access_token
if(!$access_token) $access_token = $accessToken;
```

if cannot be extended then just return the access token with 2 hours expiry
In order to post as your company page, you will need their page id.

Here is part of my script that I used to get all this working. Its not codeigniter, but you will be able to see how it works.

```
$config = array(
        'appId' => APPID,
        'secret' => APPSECRET,
);


        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $facebook->setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // Get User ID
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

        try {
                $page_id = '************'; // 
                $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
                if(!empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
                        // do your code stuff

                 }

         } catch { }
```

Hope It's Work